# In Lua, what is the right way to handle varargs which contains nil?

Tags: lua

I'm trying to create a debug print function which takes a file handle as the first argument. First, I write a function like this:

```
function fprint (f, ...)
   for i, v in ipairs{...} do
      f:write(tostring(v))
      f:write("\t")
   end
   f:write("\n")
end
```

This function works as long as I don't pass `nil` value in arguments. But if I call this with a `nil`, it doesn't print the `nil` value and rest of arguments.

```
fprint(io.stderr, 1, 2, nil, 3)
=> prints only 1 and 2
```

So, what is the right way to fix this problem?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Actually, it's easy to handle `nil` values in varargs, all you need is to use the [`select`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-select) function, which works even with `nil` (it counts the actual number of parameters). The following idiom is so useful that it is a core library function [`table.pack`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#pdf-table.pack) in Lua 5.2:

```
function table.pack(...)
  return { n = select("#", ...), ... }
end
```

The number of arguments is stored in field `n`, so in order to iterate through them just use this:

```
function vararg(...)
    local args = table.pack(...)
    for i=1,args.n do
        -- do something with args[i], careful, it might be nil!
    end
end
```

Comment: Sweet! I did't know about `select`.

Comment: A most useful addition is that you cannot just `unpack` the table anymore. In order to unpack use: `local tbl = { n = select("#", ...), ... }; print(unpack(tbl, 1, tbl.n));`

Comment: This answer was discussed in detail in the official wiki: http://lua-users.org/wiki/VarargTheSecondClassCitizen

Answer (score 4):

As best I know, there's no easy implementation independent way to know the length of an array that contains `nil` entries since the `#` operation can point to any position that is followed by a `nil`, but this is a quick implementation dependent solution that will print the `nil`.

```
function fprint (f, ...)
   local parm={...}
   for i=1,#parm do
      f:write(tostring(parm[i]))
      f:write("\t")
   end
   f:write("\n")
end
```

Rather than relaying on `#`, you can get complicated (and therefore implementation independent) since you know the `parm` table is an array and use something like this:

```
function last_index(array)
  local max = 0
  for k, _ in pairs(array) do
    max = math.max(max, k)
  end
  return max
end

function fprint (f, ...)
   local parm={...}
   for i=1,last_index(parm) do
      f:write(tostring(parm[i]))
      f:write("\t")
   end
   f:write("\n")
end
```

If you can skip the `nil` values and order isn't important, then switching to `pairs` would be much easier.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try to switch to pairs.

Comment: Obviously Michael's answer is the best, I even +1'd it myself, but is there any other reason for the down vote?

Comment: @torus: thanks. SO doesn't let you know who downvoted, so the question is more for the general public. Just wanted to be sure I'm not doing/saying something wrong. Great question, I ended up learning something new as a result. :)