# "attempt to call a nil value" when doing a generic loop

Tags: lua

I'm getting an error with Lua (standard interprteter) and I can't find the source of the problem. I am trying to create something that resembles an enum from languages like Java, C#, etc. The current code that I have to define the enum standards is this:

```
enum = {
    new = function (self, ...)
        local o = {};
        setmetatable(o, self);
        self.__index = self;
        for k,v in args do -- THIS LINE IS GIVING THE ERROR
            self[v] = 2^k;
        end
        table.sort(self, function(a,b) if a>b then return true; else return false; end end)
        return o;
    end,
    sum = function (self, ...)
        local s
        for k,v in args do
            s = s+self[v];
        end
    end,
    expand = function (self, number)
        indices = {};
        for k,v in ipairs(self) do
            if v < number then
                table.append(k);
                number = number-v;
            end
        end
        return unpack(indices);
    end
}
```

The error appears in the `new` function, in the loop statement (not the statement inside it). What can be the cause of this? I'm not "calling" the values, just referencing them.
I also tried replacing `2^k` with `math.pow(2,k)`, so it's not the math, either.
I run the following code to test the script:

```
myEnum = enum:new("a","b","c");
```

I should note that the error simply says what is on the title, no variable name or anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, a for loop of the type `for k,v in...` expects to take an iterator function, not a table; secondly, `args` is unset when you refer to it.  If you want to loop over the varargs to the function, use `for k,v in ipairs({...})`.

Note that if one of the varargs is nil, iterating with `ipairs` may stop at the nil, and iterating with `pairs` isn't guaranteed to return the varargs in the same order they were passed.  If this is a problem, a workaround can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7183998/in-lua-what-is-the-right-way-to-handle-varargs-which-contains-nil).

Comment: Thanks for the concise answer!